# CSS border on a <div> acts differently?

Tags: html, css

the title may be a little unclear, so here's a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

**[HTML & CSS Sourcecode](http://pastebin.com/5xPKxicM)**

All elements use the same CSS class, so shouldn't they all have the same width?
The bigger the border gets, the bigger the difference becomes. How do I make sure the div and the other elements have the same width?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because box sizing is different between form elements and normal HTML elements. If it's not a form element, the box model used is the one W3C used to preach where border and padding **add** to the set `width` property to make it larger than you specified.

If you don't care about legacy browser support (IE < 8, etc), you can just do this:

```
div.style {
    /* By default, browsers would have set this as content-box */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

And your border (and any existing horizontal padding) will be part of the `width` property of your `<div>`.

To do it the other way around, instead of the above:

```
button.style, textarea.style {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Again, these properties are only supported by modern browsers.

Comment: Thank you for your response, so this is how you change the div... could I also do it the other way around and change the others to match the div?

Comment: @Chris: I've updated my answer. I haven't tried it yet however.

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate it :-)

Comment: In chrome I had to set the css properties directly to div. div.style was not working at least in chrome. thanks for the solution anyway @BoltClock .